# Symfony installing doctrine

Tags: php, symfony

So here is what i did, i did use this command

```
composer require doctrine
```

and i got this message while installing, i am told that symfony was down when i tried to install this.

```
The "https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

https://flex.symfony.com/aliases.json could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Then i was told i need to install

```
 composer require symfony/orm-pack
 composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle
```

My problem is that my .env file does not contain any or any other database configurations...
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"

What is it i am doing wrong? I would be very grateful for any help..

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the use of https with composer:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```